# Cakebuild script uses vs 2017 and build fails

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, cakebuild, sitecore-habitat

I'm working on a legacy project based on Habitat home. There is a PowerShell script which I'm using since there is no cake extension for vs2019. But I'm getting those errors

> Version 2.2.300 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.0.0
>   of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is
>   15.8.169.51996. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently
>   available.

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting  .NET Core
>   2.2.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2.

I've changed the `cake-config.json` like this - `"BuildToolVersions": "VS2019"`. But nothing cahnged.

Is there another config/xml or something that has to be changed?

Comment: See [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2#sdk-2.2.401), only .net core sdk 2.2.108 is compatible with VS2017. Other versions like 2.2.205,2.2.301 and 2.2.401 don't support VS2017. So you can't use msbuild 15.0 version(build engine of VS2017) to build projects use .net core sdk 2.2.301. (The error message 15.8.169.51996 indicates you're using build tool for VS2017). Also, make sure you've installed the corresponding sdk.

Comment: Or you can try to secpify the version 2.2.108 in [global.json](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/global.json) as the error message suggests if you want to use build tools of VS2017 to  build it.